# MongoDB query using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a photo collection which stores the user, tag, date and photo url. I want a query to return the 2 latest photo for a user per tag.

e.g

```
{user: 1, date: 1, url: a, tag: tag1}
{user: 1, date: 2, url: b, tag: tag1}
{user: 1, date: 3, url: c, tag: tag1}
{user: 1, date: 4, url: d, tag: tag2}
{user: 2, date: 1, url: e, tag: tag1}
{user: 3, date: 1, url: f, tag: tag1}
```

Running the query on user 1 should return

```
{user: 1, date: 1, url: a, tag: tag1}
{user: 1, date: 2, url: b, tag: tag1}
{user: 1, date: 4, url: d, tag: tag2}
```

I am using mongoose with NodeJs.

Comment: have you looked over the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) and tried to make this query? Please update your question so we can help debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- in MongoDB 5 the easier way to do it is with `$setWindowFields`
- match the user
- group by tag(partition), sort by date, and rank(adds one field with the order of each document inside the its group)
- keep only rank < 3 (from each group keep only the 2 first)
- unset to remove the rank

*this gives the oldest, because in your expected output you have the oldest, you can change it to newest using `{"date":-1}`

*alternative solution for MongoDB <5 would be to sort by date, group by tag,
and slice to get only the first 2.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70612335-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":{"$user" : 1}},
 {"$setWindowFields":
  {"partitionBy":"$tag",
   "sortBy":{"date":1},
   "output":{"rank":{"$rank":{}}}}},
 {"$match":{"$expr":{"$lt":["$rank", 3]}}},
 {"$unset":["rank"]}])
```